# Страницы на сайте

Tags: html

Вот интересует вопрос. Предположим есть 5 страниц, в которых, например лежат статьи. Статьи вечно добавляются и следовательно создаются новые страницы и старые статьи уходят на предыдущие страницы, а новые заменяют их места.

Вопрос:  Это обычно делается все в ручную. После каждого обновления изменяют html в каждой странице?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В программировании не силен, но думаю, что общий принцип объяснить смогу. Чтобы это ни было, код на php (первый ответ) или cms (второй ответ), принцип везде один.

1) **База данных**. Скорее всего первое, что вы попробуете это будет mysql. В ячейках базы данных содержится вся информация о статье: ее содержание и заголовок, информация об авторе, комментарии, вообщем все динамическое.

2) **Програмный код**, при помощи которого вы можете обратиться к базе данных, вытащить все эти значения и сгенерировать HTML для вывода.

3) **Верстка**, но не пяти страниц, а одной, где динамические куски кода заменяются на переменные. Например:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
    <div class="content">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="comments">
        <?php echo $comments ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

(То, что с символом бакса - переменные. Echo - вывод в HTML. Вопросы и знаки больше\меньше - границы програмного кода.

Давайте посмотрим, скажем, на вконтакте, а именно на страницу пользователя. Страница существует в единственном виде, но когда мы к ней обращаемся, мы передаем значение - id пользоватяля. Програмный код на сервере обращается к базе данных, вытаскивает нужную информацию для пользователя с этим id, генерирует переменные для этой нашей единственной странице и формирует ее.

Я бы рекомендовал разбираться в таком порядке:

1) Попробуйте язык php с [самого начала](http://www.php.su/learnphp/?syntax). Обязательно прочитайте про формы, отправку данных.

2) Прочитайте раздел про [работу с базами данных](http://www.php.su/mysql/)

3) Попробуйте собственоручно написать простенькое подобие блога (уровня лабораторки в универе).

4) Пробуйте изучать "движки" для программирвоания сайтов. Это могут быть как CMS системы: wordpress или drupal, так и фреймворки: Yii Framework, например. Это все использует PHP. Можете так же посмотреть на Ruby on Rails или [ASP.net](http://ASP.net).

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Для реализации динамического изменения содержания используют скрипты, которые делают это автоматически. Например, то, что вас интересует, может делать любой серверный/клиентский язык программирования. Принцип приблизительно следующий: подсчитать кол-во статей -> вывести на экран ссылку на каждую статью (если кол-во статей больше N, вывести последовательно по N статей на каждой странице).  Чаще всего для решения придания динамичности используют [PHP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Нет, для этого есть [CMS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC). Хотя всё сугубо индивидуально, может быть кто-то это делает и в ручную.